# Finding Average based on Multiple criteria in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

[image]

Problem: Unable to average scores based on month per user

What I've tried: AVERGAEIF/IFS but unable to create a sensible syntax, , the sections per months have been created with a drop down list to Vlookup from if needed and i've data validated to create the list of names.

Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: Try: `=AVERAGEIFS($B2:$B25,$A2:$A25,$G3,$C2:$C25,TEXTBEFORE(H2," ")&"*")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, it'd be easier it you had the full month name above your headers, but you can make it work how it is, but it may require month-specific formulas.

This formula would go in H3, and you'd simply change the month name to each month. If you had the full month name you could reference those cells, or do a lookup to get them.

`=averageifs($B$2:$B$25,$C$2:$C$25,"January",$A$2:$A$25,$G3)`

As a general rule of thumb, when doing a sumifs, maxifs, etc. I use the IFS version of the formula because it's easier to add additional criteria if needed without needing to adjust the order of the formula. For example, sumifs starts with the sum range, whereas sumif ends with the sum range, so to add more criteria you'd need to move that section before the rest.

Answer (score 0):

Using `AVERAGEIFS()` function OfCourse one can do it, but to do it dynamically one can use one of the followings as well without any hardcoding: --> Uses `Wildcard Operator` --> `*` which means zero or more characters, hence for the followings, it checks after the three relevant letters of the months to find the respective in order to get the average values by names!

---

[image]

---

```
=AVERAGEIFS($B2:$B25,$A2:$A25,$G3,$C2:$C25,TEXTBEFORE(H2," ")&"*")
```

---

Or, with the help of a `LAMBDA()` helper `BYCOL()` to spill all at once:

```
=BYCOL(H2:J2,LAMBDA(x, AVERAGEIFS($B2:$B25,$A2:$A25,$G3,$C2:$C25,TEXTBEFORE(x," ")&"*")))
```

---

If one do not have access to `TEXTBEFORE()` can use `SUBSTITUTE()` function as well:

```
=AVERAGEIFS($B2:$B25,$A2:$A25,$G3,$C2:$C25,SUBSTITUTE(H$2," Average",)&"*")
```

---

Answer (score 0):

Suppose `score range` are the scores you want average and `month_range` is a range of cells with months. They are part of the same table and have the same dimension.

`=AVERAGE(FILTER(score_range,month_range='January',0)`

`FILTER()` selects from `score_range` only cells that have opposite them `January` in `month_range`. It returns an array that `AVERAGE()` then processes.

You can pass to `FILTER()` criteria from dropdown list too, of course.

Is this what you were looking for?